# Unable to read the streaming data from the single file in Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to read the streaming data from the text file which gets appended continuously using Spark streaming API "textFileStream". But unable to read the continuous data with Spark streaming. How to achieve it in Spark?

Answer (score 1):

This an expected behavior. For [file based sources](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources) (like `fileStream`):

> - The files must be created in the dataDirectory by atomically moving or renaming them into the data directory.
> - Once moved, the files must not be changed. So if the files are being continuously appended, the new data will not be read.

If you want to read continuously appended you'll have to create your own source, or use separate process, which will monitor changes, and push records to for example Kafka (though it is rare to combine Spark with file systems that support appending).