# Read HDFS file as stream

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, streaming, hdfs

I have a file in my DataLake (HDFS) `adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/Data/prod/2018/2018-02/AHA-2018-02-13.json`.

This file receive continously data from ESB. Therefore, I would like to read this file like a stream and perform action on lines. I tried this :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, batchDuration=60)
a = 'adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/Data/prod/2018/2018-02/AHA-2018-02-13.csv'
b = "adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/Data/dev/test.out"
lines = ssc.textFileStream(a)
words = lines.flatMap(lambda x : x.split(' '))
wordCounts = words.map(lambda x :  (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x+y)
wordCounts.saveAsTextFiles(b)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

This code runs without error but in my output directory `adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/Data/dev/test.out`, I can see several folders created every minute, all empty despite the fact that I know I received data.

This code above is just an example. I am currently trying to understand how to perform a stream read on my files. The first thing for me is to count words of each new line in my file. Could you please tell me what is wrong with my current code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to read the streaming data from the single file in Spark streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44337453/6910411).

Comment: @user6910411 according to your post, i tried to perform the same action by adding a new file while my process is running ... I still receive empty files as output.

Comment: It is not about adding new file as much as making _atomic_ changes. Writing to file won't do.

Comment: @user6910411 actually, I figured out what is the problem. I should monitor a folder, not a file. And currently, i am tracking a file ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from that fact that I am watching a specific file. I should be watching a folder to catch the new files. Apparently, there is no native mean to watch a file while data is being append.