# Spark streaming one log file with java doesn't generate any output

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-stream, spark-streaming

I want to stream a log file by java and spark. My code is simple:

```
  String base = "c:/test";

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("First_App").setMaster("local[2]");
    JavaStreamingContext ssc= new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Seconds.apply(1));

    JavaDStream<String> line = ssc.textFileStream(base);
    line.map(new Function<String, Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public Integer call(String v1) throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println(v1);
            int l =  v1.length();
            return l;
        }
    });

    line.print();

    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

In `c:/test` is a log file that generates with log back. Its content is :

```
INFO:Data=Do Save Entity
INFO:Data=Do Delete Entity
```

but when I run my app, following result print in the console:

```
18/02/18 19:55:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1518971130000 ms
18/02/18 19:55:30 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1518971130000 ms.0 from job set of time 1518971130000 ms
18/02/18 19:55:30 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1518971130000 ms.0 from job set of time 1518971130000 ms
18/02/18 19:55:30 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.291 s for time 1518971130000 ms (execution: 0.002 s)
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1518971130000 ms
-------------------------------------------

18/02/18 19:55:30 INFO FileInputDStream: Cleared 0 old files that were older than 1518971070000 ms: 
18/02/18 19:55:30 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches: 
18/02/18 19:55:30 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 
18/02/18 19:55:31 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 16 ms
18/02/18 19:55:31 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1518971131000 ms:

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1518971131000 ms
-------------------------------------------
```

and this output continues.
My aim is simple: stream a log file and then print its content in the console, of course, this is temporary because finally, I want to save the file in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't see any output is that `JavaStreamingContext.textFileStream` monitors a directory for newly created files ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaStreamingContext.html#textFileStream-java.lang.String-)) and does not react on changed files. Some ideas how to deal with the situation you describe are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44337753/2129801).

A second (unrelated) issue in your code is that the call to `line.map` returns a new JavaDStream on which you should call `print` to see the result of the transformation. Calling print directly on `line` will show you the contents of the stream without transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read your link. Is your mean using `fileStream` method?

Comment: No. As of now, Spark Streaming does not support streaming  the _changes_ of a file out of the box. It only supports to stream _newly created_ files. As mentioned in the linked post, "If you want to read continuously appended you'll have to create your own source". If you decide to go this way, this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html) might help.